# When is it safe to commit a FragmentTransaction?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html)

> A fragment transaction can only be created/committed prior to an
>   activity saving its state. If you try to commit a transaction after
>   Activity.onSaveInstanceState() (and prior to a following
>   Activity.onStart or Activity.onResume(), you will get an error.

I can understand that the first part that a fragment transaction can't committed after Activity.onSaveInstanceState(),
  because the state after the commit can be lost if the activity needs to be restored.

But I don't understant why we can't commit a fragment transaction prior to a Activity.onStart or Activity.onResume()? Oncreate() is also prior to Activity.onStart or Activity.onResume().Does it mean that we can't even commit it in oncreate()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key here is that you can't commit a transaction after a call to `onSaveInstanceState()` *and prior to a following* `onStart()` or `onResume()`.

You can commit transactions just fine on the initial `onCreate()` and a subsequent `onStart()` or `onResume()` because there is no state.

However, if the Activity is restoring its state (i.e. `onSaveInstanceState()` was previously called, and the Activity is recreating itself with that state, you cannot perform a Fragment transaction. This is because if you commit a Fragment transaction prior to the Activity restoring the previous Fragment state, you end up in a situation where it is unclear what state you are in. Does the saved state take precedence over the new state that you have created by committing a Fragment transaction, or should the new transaction take precedence over the saved state?

The easiest way to check for this scenario is to check if the `savedInstanceState` bundle passed to `onCreate()` and other lifecycle methods is null. If it's null, there is no saved state and you are safe to perform your transaction. If it is not null, then there is saved state that you probable want to preserve.

Comment: I don't understand why there's no state in onCreate()? Have the state not already been restored when the savedInstanceState bundle passed to onCreate()? We can retore the state in onCreate() or onRestoreInstanceState.

Comment: The state has not yet been restored in `onCreate()` because the Activity has just been created. For example, you haven't even created/set the content views yet, so there's nowhere for the saved views to go. You can restore *your* application state in `onCreate()` if you wish, but that doesn't mean that all other components have finished restoring their state.

Comment: Does it mean that setContentView() is still running when Oncreate() completes, and it will continue to run till onResume() starts to run?

Comment: `setContentView()` is not still running when `onCreate()` completes. Typically that happens inside of `onCreate()`. View state however is just one example of state that might not have been restored yet when `onCreate()` is called.

Comment: So content views have been set, savedInstanceState bundle(i.e., saved view state) has been  sent to onCreate(),can you explain why view state  has not been restored when onCreate() is called ?

Comment: Content views have *not* been set when `onCreate()` is called. Content views are usually inflated *during* `onCreate()`. It's a subtle but important difference and is the reason you can't assume state is restored at the beginning of `onCreate()`. Again, don't get too hung up on Views because they are just one piece of state that might be restored. `onRestoreInstanceState()` isn't even called until after `onStart()`, so any state being restored there (including the Activity's Window state) won't be restored until after that completes.

Comment: So content views have been set, savedInstanceState bundle(i.e., saved view state) has been  sent to onCreate(),can you explain why view state  has not been restored when onCreate() is called ?

Comment: Content views have **not** bet set when `onCreate()` is called. I don't know how else to say it. The content views are set **during** `onCreate()`. The Activity's views are typically set by the *end* of `onCreate()`, but they have not been set at the *start* of `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's safe any time **before** `onSaveInstanceState()`, which essentially means before `onPause()/onResume()`, and if your Activity ever went to `onPause()`, then it's safe only after `onResume()`.

For example, during `onActivityResult()`, you haven't actually gone to after `onResume()`, so opening a dialog in `onActivityResult()` can crash.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to bear in mind a **committed** transaction might **not** have **executed**.
This handles that:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```