# Is it safe to commit a FragmentTransaction inside onActivityResult()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentmanager

Years ago, I ran into a problem in one of my apps when I tried to commit a `FragmentTransaction` inside my `onActivityResult()` callback. Googling around, I found [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18345899/8298909), which say

> At the time that `onActivityResult()` is called, the activity/fragment's state may not yet have been restored, and therefore any transactions that happen during this time will be lost as a result.

I wound up adapting the solution recommended in the same answer for my app, and life was good. However, recent experimentation shows that perhaps things have changed, and it **may** now be safe to commit a `FragmentTransaction` from inside `onActivityResult()`.

[The documentation for (support v4) `FragmentManager.beginTransaction()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html#beginTransaction()) defines the safe window for transactions as:

> Note: A fragment transaction can only be created/committed prior to an activity saving its state. If you try to commit a transaction after `FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState()` (and prior to a following `FragmentActivity.onStart` or `FragmentActivity.onResume()`, you will get an error.

Reading [the documentation for `onActivityResult()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)), I see

> You will receive this call immediately before `onResume()` when your activity is re-starting.

This leads me to believe that it should be safe to execute these transactions in `onActivityResult()`, as `onStart()` will have already been called, putting me inside the safe window.

I made an app to test this out, and I'm successfully seeing dialog fragments that I create and commit inside `onActivityResult()`. I had the same app also log the activity lifecycle callbacks so I could inspect their order, and I see `onStart()`, then `onRestoreInstanceState()`, and then `onActivityResult()` every time.

Am I missing something? Or has the framework changed and `onActivityResult()` is now guaranteed to be a safe place for fragment transactions? Does this behavior vary by API level?

I found [another question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40490565/8298909) that seems to read the documentation the same way I have, but both are over a year old and neither specifically refers to `onActivityResult()` as a safe place for transactions.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html

Comment: @elmorabea That blog post is one of the materials I found back when I first had this issue. However, as illustrated by azizbekian's answer below, it seems that it is no longer an accurate explanation of the safe windows to commit FragmentTransactions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**A little dive into sources**

There is a boolean variable inside [`FragmentManager`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/oreo-release/fragment/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java) class, called [`mStatedSaved`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/oreo-release/fragment/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#676). This variable keeps track of the saved state depending on the activity's lifecycle callbacks. [Here's](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/oreo-release/fragment/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#2041) the method, that throws well-known exception:

```
    private void checkStateLoss() {
        if (mStateSaved) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState");
        }
        ...
    }
```

This means, that as soon as this variable is changed to `false`, then fragment transactions are free to be executed. This variable would become `true`, when the state of the activity is being saved, i.e. `onSaveInstanceState()`.

---

**Back to the question**

You said, that previously you had problems commiting a transaction from `onActivityResult()`. That should mean, that previously `mStateSaved` was not being assigned `false` and currently it is. In deed it is so.

Here's [`onActivityResult()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/oreo-release/fragment/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java#133) implementation from O release:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        mFragments.noteStateNotSaved();
        ...
    }
```

Where, [`noteStateNotSaved()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/oreo-release/fragment/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#3151) would do following:

```
    public void noteStateNotSaved() {
        ...
        mStateSaved = false;
        ...
    }
```

On the contrary, you can see the implementation of [`onActivityResult()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/jb-release/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java#139) of Jelly Bean release:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        int index = requestCode>>16;
        if (index != 0) {
            index--;
            if (mFragments.mActive == null || index = mFragments.mActive.size()) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Activity result fragment index out of range: 0x"
                        + Integer.toHexString(requestCode));
                return;
            }
            Fragment frag = mFragments.mActive.get(index);
            if (frag == null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Activity result no fragment exists for index: 0x"
                        + Integer.toHexString(requestCode));
            } else {
                frag.onActivityResult(requestCode&0xffff, resultCode, data);
            }
            return;
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Nothing would change the value of `mStateSaved` field, which would make an exception to be thrown if a transaction is committed.

In fact, the line `mFragments.noteStateNotSaved()` [was introduced](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/kitkat-release/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java#151) in Kit-Kat release. As you can see by the [commit's comment](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/4ccc001f3f883190ac8d900c4f69d71fda94690e%5E%21/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java) made by Dianne Hackborn:

> ActivityFragment should clear the flag that state is saved when it
>   receives `onNewIntent()`.  This can happen before the activity is
>   resumed, so we may not have cleared it yet.  Also need to do the same
>   thing for `onActivityResult()`.

**Sum up**

> Is `onActivityResult()` now guaranteed to be a safe place for fragment transactions?

Assuming you are using sources that include [commit 4ccc001](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/4ccc001f3f883190ac8d900c4f69d71fda94690e), which was made in October 2012 - yes, it is a safe place for fragment transactions.

Comment: Reading answers like this one is a pure joy. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, @Vasiliy, enjoying your answers/talks also.

Comment: @azizbekian Of course I want to echo the other commenters that this was a great answer, but I also want to say that the only reason I didn't instantly accept + award is that I wanted to wait and see if anyone else chimed in. Thanks for being so detailed; it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @azizbekian Thanks for the such deep explanation . By reading the code i assume the `super.onActivityResult` should be first line inside `onActivityResult` not the last cause this is call which set the `mStateSaved` to false .. Am i Right ?

Comment: @ADM, unless you have a specific reason for not putting `super` call in the top, I cannot see why you should move it to the bottom. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah .. I don't have any specific reason . But i have seen in lots of Code some of mine too (old time) .. The code above also has it at bottom .. Thanks that's Clear enough.. Super call should be first ..